# How do I call data from the database as an array and then echo each value from the array?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm new to coding.

CONTEXT
I have one table 'online_event' that holds the details to my event page. I have another table 'event_gallery' that holds the photos to the same event page. The primary key in 'online_event' is the foreign key in 'event_gallery'

so one event from 'online_event' can have multiple photos inside the 'event_gallery' table.

I'm able to retrieve one photo in the event_gallery table by using the foreign key (which is just the event id).

My question is, how can I call all pictures? it's only echoing the first of 3 photos i have saved in the table with that id number.

```
$gallery_table =  Eventgallery::find_by_id($_GET['id']);
        if($gallery_table){

            $images = $gallery_table->image_name;

        }

      print_r($images);
```

Here is the function that retrieves the data

```
  public static function find_by_id($id){
    global $database;
    $the_result_array = static::find_by_query("SELECT * FROM " . static::$db_table. " WHERE id = $id");
        return !empty($the_result_array) ? array_shift($the_result_array) : false; //ternary operator

    }
```

Because the method is returning an array_shift, shouldn't the variable I created ($images) be an array? When I print_r() it comes out as just 1 result, not an array.

Once I have it as an array, i want to loop through it and echo it all out.

Thank you

Comment: Because you are using `array_shift()` on the result array. `array_shift()` removes the first element from a provided array and returns its value.

If you want the entire array don't use `array_shift()` on it. return it as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array_shift() function is used to remove the first element from an array, and returns the value of the removed element so your getting only one image. If you want all the data your code should be like this:

```
public static function find_by_id($id){
    global $database;
    $the_result_array = static::find_by_query("SELECT * FROM " . static::$db_table. " WHERE id = $id");
        return empty($the_result_array) === false ? $the_result_array : [];
    }
```

Comment: Okay great! this brought me one step closer.

Comment: Accept the answer.